# A small part of my data is non-stationary, how to solve the issue?

Tags: forecasting, arima, stationarity, finance

For a project, I have to produce an ARIMA forecast of Boeing's stock returns over the last 10 years. I've tried to check stationarity of data with ACF first and found out that lag 1 is statistically significant.

[image]

After observing the graphical representation of my time-serie, I found out the origin of this discrepancy. In the biggest part of the dataset Boeing's returns are stationary, but around 2020 and the covid-19 outbreak, returns significantly decrease, and then significantly increase, hence violating stationarity (the mean is not the same on this period).
[image]

Do you have an idea of how I can work out that ? Differencing wouldn't do the trick I suppose...

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: It's really good that you're being critical of your assumptions. I do wonder however, if this "blip" really matters? It's roughly 2/3rds of the way through your time series, so if your model is an AR(1) model (lag 1 is significant, so this seems sensible). In an AR(1) process, the prediction at the next time point is formulated from only the current value and the model parameters. Therefore, this blip may have minimal influence on predictions.

If all you care about is forecasting, I'd see if the forecasts from simple AR(p) models are reasonable before getting yourself into non-stationarity.